# "Otherwise", "if not" and "or"

Tags: word-choice

Which one of the following choices fits better in my self-made sentence's blank:

> - Get out of here.........you’ll get beat up.
>
> **a)** otherwise
>
> **b)** if not
>
> **c)** or

I need the most natural one which a native speaker would say.
For me they all work, though 'a' sounds a bit formal for such a context, while 'b' and 'c' both work properly and naturally.

Comment: 3rd is best fit, convenient... 2nd one can be used in movies, plays.. and 1st looks like dictionary phrase ;)

Comment: Ist and 3rd should be the choices to be opted out if you are using them formally.  The second one is the most likely to be used in informal talks (the third one can fit here also).

Comment: The second one **does not** sound fluent to this native US English speaker at all.  "If not" is usually only used to begin a sentence, not as a conjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these sentences

> Get out of here **otherwise** you’ll get beat up.
>   Get out of here **or** you’ll get beat up.

refer to action and consequence in a fluid way.

> *(You had better)* get out of here **if not** you’ll get beat up.
>   *if you don't get out of here, you'll get beat up*

The "if not" needs a setup/explaination for the "if".